# Multiply two multi-dimension lists

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

For example,

```
Price = [['1', '5'], ['4', '9']]

Quantity = [['50.00', '0'], ['10.00', '20.00']]
```

want to  have

```
Revenue = [['50.00', '0'], ['40.00', '180.00']]
```

Tried using list comprehension, but don't know how it works for this two-dimension lists.

Answer (score 2):

You can do so without any modules by using the built-in function `zip`:

```
Revenue = []
for ps, qs in zip(Price, Quantity):
    rs = []
    for p, q in zip(ps, qs):
        rs.append('%.2f' % (float(p) * float(q)))
    Revenue.append(rs)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using list comprehensions

```
>>> [ [str(float(p[0]) * float(q[0])), str(float(p[1]) * float(q[1]))]  for p, q in 
zip(price, quantity) ]
[['50.0', '0.0'], ['40.0', '180.0']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the most readable, but a possible one liner to do this:

```
Revenue = [map(lambda (price,quantity) : str(float(price)*float(quantity)), zip(Price[i],Quantity[i])) for i in range(len(Price))]
```

Comment: Using `int` and `str`, this discards any decimals and returns the string `"50"` which probably isn't what the OP intended.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy and obvious to write in [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) (or [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)) if either of these an option for you, then it's just:

```
Revenue = Price*Quantity
```

In the full program:

```
import numpy as np
Price = np.array( [[1, 5], [4, 9]] )
Quantity = np.array( [[50.0, 0], [10.00, 20.00]] )

Revenue = Price*Quantity

# [[  50.    0.]
#  [  40.  180.]]
```

Note, that here I abandoned the OP's string notation.  I assume that it's a beginner's mistake, and that they want numbers to be numbers, and plan on doing more calculations than this simple one.